# How does Newton's 3rd Law work in this scenario? Why is my reasoning wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I came across this example question in my mechanics book:

[image]

It's a light scale pan with negligible mass, with two blocks **A** and **B**, with masses **0.4kg** and **0.6kg** respectively. The pan is attached to a string.

[image]

A tension T (10.3N) is then applied to the string, causing the scale pan to accelerate at **0.5m/s/s**.

```
The question is to work out the force exerted on B by A.
```

The book explains that the best way to go about this is to work out the force exerted  on A by B, and then use Newton's 3rd Law to then say that A will exert an equal and opposite force on B.

[image]

So it's just a simple matter of working out **R**, giving 4.12N, meaning 4.12N is exerted on A by B, thus meaning A exerts the same force on B.

What I don't understand this, is why do we ignore the gravitational acceleration of A? If A is sitting on B, does that not mean that A will also be exerting a force of **0.4g** on B? Since this isn't the case, why isn't this so? And what would it entail if I did include A's gravitational acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

If the masses were not accelerating, it would be the case that B exerts an upward force on A equal to

$$F_{AB} = (0.4)\cdot(9.81) \mathrm N = 3.92 \mathrm N$$

in order to cancel the downward force of gravity.

Since A *is* accelerating upward, it must be that B exerts a *greater* force equal to

$$F_{BA} =  (0.4) \cdot (9.81 + 0.5) = 4.12 \mathrm N $$

So gravity isn't ignored; B must exert a force equal to the weight of A *plus* the force required to accelerate the mass of A upward.

Comment: Ok, but what about the 4.12N that A then exerts on b. What's the significance of that? Does that ensure that it remains seated on B?